# write a dictionary with python 3 with entrance feature

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanna to write a dictionary with python.
i want first the user enters the number of words which wish to register ( for example 5 words)
in the next step, the program gets some words with their meaning  (the user enter each word and its meaning in a line and separated by a space)
After that, the program get a sentence from the user and translate based on the input's words.
If a word on the sentence wasn't in the input's word the program use it.
i dont have any idea, please help me

Input:

5

hello salam

goodbye khodafez

say goftan

we ma

you shoma

we say goodbye to you tonight

output:

ma goftan khodafez to shoma tonight

thanks

Comment: Ok, so presumably you have written some code? What are you struggling with and what is your question? At the moment this is just a statement of what you want. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you already know how to use dictionaries, it should be a case of looping through the dictionary's items and doing something like `sentence.replace(key, value)`

Comment: actully i'm not a programer and just want to use this progrom for a certain job.

Comment: if you help me, i really appriciate it

Comment: @NChauhan  would work, but is not as efficient as iterating through the words in the sentence and replacing them if in the dictionary as dict lookup is `O(1)` (average case) whereas replacing occurrences in a string is roughly `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    my_dic = {}
    final = ""

    how_many = int(input("Enter the number : "))

    for i in range(0,how_many):
        input_sentence = list( (input("Enter your %d sentence : " %(i+1))).split(" ") )
        my_dic[input_sentence[0]] = input_sentence[1]

    input_sentence = list(input("Enter your statement that needs to decode : ").split(" "))
    for word in input_sentence:
        if word in my_dic:
            final += my_dic[word]
        else:
            final += word
        final += " "

    print(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should attempt to give this ago yourself, but I don't mind getting you started with something:

```
no_words = int(input('number of words: '))
print('enter word translations, one per line, separated by a space')
words = {a:b for a,b in (input().split() for _ in range(no_words))}
sentence = input('sentence to translate:\n')
translation = ' '.join(words[w] if w in words else w for w in sentence.split())
print(translation)
```

which works as expected:

```
number of words: 2
enter word translations, one per line, separated by a space
fish cat
mouse dog
sentence to translate:
my fish ate a mouse
my cat ate a dog
```

Comment: really approciate it

Answer (score 1):

My approach:

```
translate = {}
while True:
    ans = input('enter word followed by space then its translation: (Enter nothing to continue)\n')
    if not ans:
        break
    else:
        word, *translation = ans.split()
    translate[word] = ' '.join(translation)
sentence = input('enter sentence: ')
sentence = sentence.split()
for i in range(len(sentence)):
    try:
        sentence[i] = translate[sentence[i]]
    except KeyError:
        pass
sentence = ' '.join(sentence)
print(sentence)
```

Comment: Does iterating in the fashion `for word in sentence' work for changing elements during iteration?